# What is Khronos EGL and where can I find an open source implementation?

Tags: opengl

http://www.khronos.org/egl/

Is EGL a windowing and input framework for OpenGL like GLFW, SDL or GLUT?
Is there a complete implementation yet?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it replaces the platform-specific [WGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiggleWin32)/[AGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Graphics_Library)/[GLX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX) calls with a cross-platform set.

I haven't run across any *complete* free implementations, though there appear to be [some hacks](http://hoegsberg.blogspot.com/2009/07/eagle-egl-loader.html) out there if you dig a bit.